# Return a 404 when a resource is not found in Spring Boot

Tags: java, rest, spring, spring-mvc

I wrote this code in order to return a http status of not found to my users in case the resource is not present in the DB.

```
@RestController
public class ExampleController {

    public final ExampleService exampleService;

    @Autowired
    public ExampleController(ExampleService exampleService) {
        this.exampleService = exampleService;
    }

    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/mappings/get-by-id/{id}")
    public ExampleDto getExampleById(@PathVariable String id) {
        Example example = exampleService.findById(id).orElse(null   );
        if (example == null) throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
        return new ExampleDto(example);
    }

}
```

I would like to know if this code can be considered good and robust enough or if it can be improved and how.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to type  `@Autowired` on constructor injection. Cheers just saved 2 line of code in each Component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your URL path isn't very RESTlike. You have built the URL to describe an operation when a more common approach is to build the URL to describe a [resource](https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/).

So instead of `https://example.com/api/mappings/get-by-id/42` one would build a URL like `https://example.com/api/mappings/42`.

The name `get-by-id` is fully redundant in REST world as the "get" operation is already defined in the HTTP GET-method (the `@GetMapping` annotation in Spring Boot) and identifying resources by their identifier is always the default operation :).

Comment: While that is correct this is a specific case where you can get an item by a property that I called id here but it was just to write an example.
The key part of my question if how to handle the 404. 

Thanks for your contribution in any case!

Comment: Ps 
I have made my pseudocode more precise regarding your observation.
xxxId is a specific property of my object, therefore the route I specified.

Comment: Still you have a very valid point, +1

Answer (score 1):

As often happens after sleeping on it I had a better solution:

```
.orElseThrow(ResourceNotFoundException::new);
```